# How come air masses displace air when it moves rather than mixing with it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, atmospheric-science, air, meteorology

It seems if you had one mass or air moving towards another air mass, that the molecules within that first air mass would be able to penetrate into the second air mass because the distance between air molecules is so great. However it seems we assume there is no mixing, why?

Comment: Duplicate [Why don't different air masses mix immediately?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7317/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe they do mix, its just due to the timescales for most problems its usually easier to ignore it due to the time for the mixing to occur, usually there is some dynamic inhibiting mechanical mixing, such as denser air underneath lighter air.